# window.localstorage failing on IOS safari, out of incognito mode

Tags: javascript, ios, local-storage, mobile-safari

Localstorage stopped working after the last iOS update on all our IOS devices, yet we can't seem to find any reference online to that change, and wondering what's going on.

I have a jsfiddle implementing basic localstorage setting and getting.
It runs without issue on Chrome (IOS) but fail entirely on Safari:
https://jsfiddle.net/mva3ap87/

Here is the code:

```
 var ls = {
    set:    function() {
        if (window.localStorage && window.localStorage.setItem) {
            window.localStorage.setItem('hello','world');
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    },
    get:    function() {
        if (window.localStorage && window.localStorage.getItem) {
            return window.localStorage.getItem('hello');
        } else {
            return 'nope';
        }
    }
}

$('.status1').html(window.localStorage?'Yes':'No');
$('.status2').html(ls.set()?'Success':'Failure');
$('.status3').html(ls.get());
```

This issue affect all the IOS devices we have tried.

Incognito mode is not on.
No popup blocker active."Do not track" is off.
Cookies are allowed (but shouldn't matter anyway).

Any clue what's going on?

**Update:**

I was able to borrow a mac and found the error:

"DOM Exception 22: An attempt was made to add something to storage that exceeed the quota".

The localstorage is empty, and the browser is not in incognito mode.

I'm even more confused.

Comment: So what is the result of `ls.get()`? Any errors in the console?

Comment: What IOS version? I'm running 9.3.2 and don't have this issue. https://jsfiddle.net/64ykam60/

Comment: Is this getting printed: $('.status1').html(window.localStorage?'Yes':'No');

Comment: It fails entirely, nothing is displayed, none of the html() is executed.

I'm on windows, no access to mac, can't make the hacky solutions work on windows to debug and pinpoint the issue.

"window.localStorage && window.localStorage.getItem" resolves to true, yet "window.localStorage.setItem('hello','world');" triggers a JS error.

Comment: using http://jsconsole.com (the only kind-of viable option for remote-debugging from windows to IOS) just outputs "Script error." without a line or any details.

Comment: I was able to borrom a mac, the error is: "DOM Exception 22: An attempt was made to add something to storage that exceeed the quota" but local storage is empty (not a single object in there) and the browser is not in incognito mode.